# Not able to understand how to call iframe tag to download a file from trmote machine

Tags: html, jsp, iframe

Can some one provide me an example code to access the remote machine file using iframes

E.g.: my remote machine is having an ip of `10.127.0.0` and i have a file in `C:\file1`

Can i write like?

```
iframe src="10.127.0.0//c:/file1"
```

Is above tag works properly in JSP code?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible at all for security reasons.

You need to either set up the remote site to serve the desired files through the web server, so you can access them the usual way like

```
http://10.127.0.0/files/file1
```

one easy way to do that in Apache is the [Alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_alias.html) directive.

or use a different method altogether to get hold of the files, like a network share.